# What is the difference between pointers and pointers with allocated memory?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
sstruct *temp1;
sstruct *p;
sstruct *temp2=new sstruct;
```

If  I try to do something like this

```
temp1=p;
temp2=p;
```

is there any diffrence?

Comment: Yeah, you leak memory with the second one.

Comment: This is dangerous and UB. `p` is not initialized and may point to anywhere (and definitely not to a valid object)

Comment: Aren't both assignments UB, technically?

Comment: both are UB as p is uninitialized. Else `temp2=p;` would create a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `p` is not explicitly initialized. So if this is a local variable it has an *indeterminate value*. If, OTOH., it's in namespace scope, then it's zero-initialized.

Assuming that it's an indeterminate value the subsequent assignment `temp1=p` has Undefined Behavior. Anything might happen. These things that can happen include (1) nothing, and (2) a crash.

If nothing happens, then the second assignment, `temp2=p`, loses the original value of `temp2`, which was the pointer to a dynamically allocated object. So this then is a memory leak. On top of the Undefined Behavior.

---

In original Pascal pointers always pointed to dynamically allocated objects. There was no way to take the address of a variable. This was a somewhat higher level view of pointers, and the Pascal pointers were single object pointers, not pointers to arrays.

In original C, which C++ was based on, pointers were more like low level memory addresses. A C or C++ pointer value can be obtained by using the address operator, `&`, on some object. Or you can get a pointer as an implicit conversion of an expression referring to an array (you then get a pointer to the array's first item).

---

There are three main notations for denoting a nullvalue of pointer type.

```
int* p = 0;              // Core language, original C.
int* p = nullptr;        // Core language, C++11 and later.
int* p = NULL;           // Library, `<stddef.h>`.
```

I recommend using the newer `nullptr` notation.

It's more readable and it fares better when used with so called perfect forwarding (whose main imperfection is that it doesn't deal correctly with 0, forwarding it as an `int` value).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since `p` is uninitialized you invoke undefined behavior by reading from it (if the code is in function scope). But for the following code

```
sstruct *temp1;
sstruct *p = nullptr;
sstruct *temp2=new sstruct;

temp1=p;
temp2=p;
```

both assignments are no different (sans the destination). `temp1` and `temp2` are left with `nullptr` value and the struct you previously allocated for `temp2` has been leaked.